# iOS:Debuging universal links

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ssl, xcode9

I'm trying to implement universal links but for some reason when I load link from the domain I'm trying to redirect to my app is not working. Here is my `apple-app-site-association` file:

```
{
        "applinks": {
                "apps": ["44ABCDFG.com.myTeam.MyApp"],
                "details": [{
                        "appID": "44ABCDFG.com.myTeam.MyApp",
                        "paths": ["*"]
                }]
        }
}
```

I add the domain in the `Associated Domains`:

[image]

Here is my implantation on app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler{

    NSLog(@"universal links are working!!!");

    return true;
}
```

The links are http but per documentation it shouldn't be a issue. Also per documentation the `apple-app-site-association` is not necessary to be signed with SSL certificate.

I [use apple validation tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool) and I'm getting this error: `Error cannot fetch app site association`

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or what can I do to make this work?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using https? If not, then there are more requirements than simply hosting an apple-app-site-association json.

Answer (score 0):

According to official document, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

> The apps key in an apple-app-site-association file must be present and its value must be an empty array, as shown in Listing 6-1.